# Sensitive permission issue while publishing my new app

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I have created an Android app after months of hard work and when it came to publishing, Google straight away rejected it.
Google says i am using a sensitive permission PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS. To use this permission either my app shall be a default call handler or my core feature shall fall under the exceptions they have provided. If my core feature doesn't fall under those exceptions which it actually doesn't, then i must report a new use case. I reported new use case properly and waited for two weeks NO RESPONSE. I tried publishing my app again as exception "device automation". It got rejected again saying my app doesn't fall under this exception.

Basically what my app does is, base on phone number to which call is being made, it shows some personalize data on an overlay screen over dialer. ( Cannot tell you the complete details, i am really sorry for that). No it is not a caller id or spam detection either.

I went through Google document over and over to see if i missed something. 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=en
I couldn't find any.

My time and money has been invested in this and i can't start showing it to people.

If someone came across same issue and able to resolve it please help.

And if more details required please comment i will provide.

Comment: i dont think you'll find answers here, see this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the similar problem with Google a while ago but with this sensitive permission.

From my experience - the chances that the use case you submitted will be approved is near zero.

There are two things you can do in this case:

- either extend your app to fall under one the exception cases.
- or go the path I went - change your app main purpose to be the default dialer and your current main feature would be just a minor perk. (make it extendable to add more minor features in  future)

This is the easiest way to publish your app. Well frankly I see it as the only solution possible - Google is known for its strict "You are banned and I'm not gonna change my decision" policy. Youtube and Play Store have tens of thousands ban stories non of which is ended in a user beneficial way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Paul Ost for considering my question and answering it. I awarded the bounty.